# How to install serif pageplus x8 on ubuntu

Tags: wine

I'm fairly new to Linux.

I've downloaded and installed Wine and Serif PagePlus X8, which I've extracted. It looks like it was put into Root.

I ran setup.exe, but only got more files, actually folders, that appear to be in Root:
.rsrc
.data
.rdata
.text
CERTIFICATE

I find no files on my Windoze box to copy other than a screenshot of the product key, yet PagePlus runs there.

In case anyone's familiar with PagePlus X8, recently when saving a .ppp as a pdf, it only converts half the pages in the document. Tried telling it manually to print all pages, giving it the full range, but no cigar.

Comment: Check https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=999 .

Comment: Thanks Nurbert (sorry, don't know how to type a circumflex U), I had checked out that page before posting here. I didn't find anything useful there. I think it's for folks in the Windoze world